# Set Maven repository directory

Tags: maven-2, hudson

I'm using the Continuous Integration Software "Hudson" to build Maven 2 projects. The Hudson server is deployed in a Tomcat running with the privileges of the "www-data" User on a Debian machine. When Hudson runs Maven to build a project then it complains that it can't write to the repository "/var/www/.m2". /var/www is the Home-Directory of the www-data User. I don't want this directory in /var/www. How can I configure Hudson or Maven to use an other directory for the Maven repository?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure the path to the local repository by setting the `<localRepository>` element (which defaults to `~/.m2/repository`) of the [`settings.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0/maven-settings/settings.html):

```
<settings>
  ...
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
  ...
</settings>
```

The default location for the settings file is `~/.m2/settings.xml` (but you can specify an alternate path for the user settings file using `-s,--settings <arg>` when invoking maven).